# Could you make a rabble into a cavalrymen?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, medieval

I'm worldbuilding a low fantasy story roughly based on a old world between 600-1100 AD, but with completely different geography. The people are based on historical nations of that period but with many differences.

There is an important pass that a kingdom wants to keep under control for strategic reasons. From the outside of the kingdom there is a large arid and semi arid borderland (desert & steppe) that is thinly populated. On the nearby hills & mountains there are  hostile clans.  The agriculture is only possible on the short strip around the river.

The borderland collects little taxes, but requires large military expenses to keep it under modicum of control. Thus current king as everyone of his predecessors before him prefers to spend as little as possible.

In charge of the borderland is a military order comprised of three parts.

- Transients. 5% Heavy cavalry, temporary assigned to the borderland. Each count is required to send certain number of cavalrymen for certain period. They rotate on assigned intervals.
- Volunteers. 5% The permanent leadership of the order are those who "volunteered" to serve in the borderland. Disgraced officers, nobleman with too many gambling debts, some idealists, those who wants to prove their valor in the battles, illegitimate sons, exiles fallen out of court's favor. They could technically leave the order but rarely do.
- Rabble. 90% Conscripts sent to the borderland to fill in the ranks. Vagrants, criminals, drunks, those too poor to pay the head tax, orphans, beggars, occasional rebel. They are sent to serve in the borderland for a 5 to 10 years depending on the cause. If they desert before term is over they are executed [night's watch style](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Night%27s_Watch) Few have any military training, some peasants might know to ride, poor city people lack even that. Some are physically smaller due to being undernourished during childhood.

The order has to:

- protect colonist villages by the river delta
- protect trading caravans
- slow down invaders until royal army mobilizes.

Beside the rare invasion or highland tribe rebellion  most of the enemies are raiders:

- steppe raiders from the east
- desert raiders from the south
- river raiders from the north
- highland brigands from the west

Since 90% of the order is made of rabble, could you train 10% of them to become a cavalry thus doubling the number of horseman?

[Rounceys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouncey) & basic cavalry equipment could be acquired by the order.

Comment: Very similar to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/171316/how-long-would-it-take-to-train-peasants-into-useful-troops if your peasants stay for 4+ years some of them could become somewhat useful troops. Assuming they care enough to train or you could force them or bribe them to do it.

Comment: Horses historically have been valuable enough to be worth stealing. The cheapskate king might want to reconsider handing lots of valuable horses over to untrustworthy rabble. It might be much cheaper, for example, to use politics and intrigue to keep the clans from becoming troublesome.

Comment: as Thucydides already say in the answer and others in this comment horse is expensive and require quite long time to train, but what about dragoon or mobile/mounted infantry or even chariot instead? at least it just focus on training how to ride without learn how to fight while riding so it will shorten the training, i remember some answer that mention how long training regarding riding horse is and its pretty short if remember correctly (cant found it though) but thats the conventional one though, if we talk mongol riding and without saddle well......

Comment: @Li Jun: From my limited experience & reading, it's rather more difficult to drive a horse, at least with carriage/buggy/wagon (don't know anyone who does chariots :-)), than it is to ride.

Comment: @jamesqf i believe you, never ride horse or chariot equivalent myself, i guess its harder to maneuver while make the horse in synch and can end up stumble or something, considering most war chariot usually need more than one horse. not considering terrain problem.

Comment: @Li Jun: I think it's more that when you're riding a well-trained horse, you can mostly control it with very subtle cues: weight shifts, knee pressure, very light pressure on the reins.  If you're really good (I'm not!) you can even ride without a bridle at all.  See for instance some on-line videos of Stacey Westfall.  Being able to do that would allow you to use both hands for a bow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, cavalry has been the role of the nobility, not the "rabble", for the very simple reason that horses are expensive. They require a great deal of forage (one horse eats about the same amount as 10 men), must be trained to operate as cavalry mounts, require expensive stabling, support (blacksmiths, veterinarians and so on), special protection (barding) and special saddles if your setting has stirrups (the knight's saddle is much different from a riding saddle, in order to support him as he strikes and prevent him from being unhorsed). Even in Classical Greece and Ancient Rome, Cavalry was the arm of the aristocracy ("Aristoi" in Greece, and the Equites in Rome).

European cavalry also required a lot of horses in your analogous time period, riding horses for the Knight and squires, pack animals to carry all the gear and of course the war horses themselves. Even more modern cavalry units still needed pack animals and replacement mounts in large numbers.

All this required extensive training, and European knights and Japanese Samurai started training in childhood. In feudal Japan, Samurai were forbidden to engage in trade, while in Europe, Knights generally fed off the local population in exchange for protection, in order to essentially train full time.

So "rabble" are not going to have the wealth to purchase horses and equipment, and generally are going to be starting training well past the ideal time that knights started (about 7 years old). You could also suggest that the sort of lifestyle the rabble led prior to being pressed into service isn't going to give them either the self discipline needed to really excel at learning martial arts. They likely also are smaller and weaker in stature and health than a member of the aristocratic class, so won't even have the same degree of strength and endurance.

The two possible options that can be explored would be to train the "cream of the crop" to act as light cavalry, in other words scouts, skirmishers and couriers to bring messages back and forth. These individuals would not participate in battles directly, but would be useful in providing the commander intelligence about the enemy, guarding the flanks, harassing the enemy and other useful tasks. They would be auxiliaries to the main cavalry arm. As a bonus, they wouldn't disturb the social order of the garrison, since they would not be considered equals to the aristocratic cavalry, nor would they even be around much if they are actually doing their jobs.

The second option would be to whip the rabble into some sort of fighting shape as pikemen, with the "cream of the crop" becoming Sergeants in charge of small groups of men. Given that there is some threat which requires dealing with, Pikemen provide a simple and inexpensive way to field a large force which is capable of taking to the field and dealing effectively with a warrior class trained since childhood (i.e. enemy aristocratic cavalry). Blocks of pikes can provide the hard "core" of a fighting formation, with crossbows interspersed between blocks to provide long range attacks, sword or axemen for close protection and the cavalry sheltering behind until the enemy is disordered enough to warrant a charge. This is effectively the "Infantry Revolution" style of fighting which emerged in the mid 1400's, and was effective enough to evolve into "shot and pike" warfare with the introduction of gunpowder, and early black powder warfare was based on many of the principles of "Infantry Revolution" warfare even into the late 1700's.

Now this is also contingent upon what sort of threat you are facing. If the enemy is Mongol horse armies, then you likely won't have a setup as described anyway - that force will be mowed down. You would need lots of your own cavalry, or heavy infantry, and lots of engineer troops to build castles and other defences. Other sorts of threats might require other sorts of responses.

So in general, a "rabble" isn't going to be converted into any sort of cavalry quickly or easily, and will most likely be more useful as a light cavalry supporting the main force. The better and historically more effective use of a "rabble" is to make them infantry soldiers with proper weapons and tactics to deal with a skilled "warrior" class.